# What is the best way to to handle timeout issues in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeout

Selenium WebDriver version 4.1.0.  .Net Visual Studio 2019

I am having problems with getting a timeout to work.  The code shown below for setting timeout on GetEnabledElement does not.  Any object identifier that uses this is failing as the test does not wait for the object to be enabled.  It is the same with GetVisibleElement.  I can't see what the problem in the code is.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
 public static IWebElement GetEnabledElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by) => GetEnabledElement(driver, by, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    public static IWebElement GetEnabledElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
        return wait.Until(d =>
        {
            var element = d.FindElement(by);
            return element.Enabled ? element : null;
        });
    }
```

I then use this in the identification of elements as follows:

```
IWebElement lnkBlah => Driver.GetEnableElement(By.XPath("//img@alt='House icon"));
```

It continually fails until I add in a Thread.Sleep(1000), which suggests the timeout code is not doing anything.

Comment: Incase `Thread.Sleep(1000)` works why not `GetEnabledElement(driver, by, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))` or bigger?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  It fails immediately, which suggests it is not waiting for the 10 seconds.

Comment: Is it necessary you write a seperate method `GetEnabledElement()` where as you can just use a inbuilt method?

Comment: We were using something like this on every element to be clicked: 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            IWebElement btnCouncilTax = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath...

but that meant we had a lot of duplicate code.  We're tyring to reduce duplication by creating GetEnabledElement() and GetVisibleElement()

Comment: `ElementToBeClickable()` ensures element is enabled and clickable, why the additional `GetEnabledElement()`?